# Virtual box guest (Win 10/Ubuntu minimal) without IP on Ubuntu 18 host

Tags: virtualbox, internet, dhcp

I have traversed multiple tutorials/solutions on how to run win or linux guest on Virtual Box (there are many) but not a single one provided a solution to me.

**Host setup**

- Ubuntu 18
- Virtual Box 5.2.16 r123759
- connection - wifi interface

**Virtual box setup**

- bridged adapter on wifi interface
- adapter type - pcnet fast III (or Intel pro 1000 desktop)
- cable connected checked

**Guests**

- Win 10 and Ubuntu minimal installation iso files

Both guests expect DHCP will assign them an IP from the network before installing but this does not happen.

Any suggestions where to look for causes of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the cause was that in order to log into the corporate wifi network username and password is needed. I could not provide these before any of the OS was installed so I used wired network in order to proceed with installation process.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is usage of bridged adapter on wifi interface. In general wifi doesn't support bridging natively.
If you want bridged adapter use it on wired network.

Comment: Hi @taurhel, thx for advice. Apparently this is not the case. I have switched wifi networks from corporate to home and suddenly everything worked. I will investigate further what configuration of our wifi is causing this.